# Compute simliarity between two sets of numbers with each set summing up to 100%?

Tags: similarities

I have product shares for different users. Need to find similarity between users based on these product shares.

For Example,

User 1
Prod A: 44%
Prod B: 33%
Prod C: 23%

User 2
Prod A: 76%
Prod B: 24%
Prod C: 0%

Comment: Nice review of similarity measures between compositional data or between probability mass functions: Sung-Hyuk Cha, Comprehensive Survey on Distance/Similarity measures between.... easy to find in the internet.

Comment: Welcome to the site, @Mohit Raut. To improve your question, please could you provide details about what approaches/methods you have considered/tried so far, and what it is that you are unsure about or what problems you've encountered and need help to solve?